# How to create tree with div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I try to create divs with several levels of indentation depending on the element before.

I saw that we could create trees with "ul" and "li" but I have to use divs for my case )=

```css
#container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container div {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.element {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

[data-id=title-2] {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

[data-id=title-3] {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#container [data-id=title-2]~.element {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#container [data-id=title-3]~.element {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="element">Element A</div>

  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-3">Title 3</div>
  <div class="element">Element B</div>

  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="element">Element C</div>
</div>
```

I want my "element C" to be aligned with my "title-2" because it is preceded by a "title-2".

https://jsfiddle.net/ghncdfpt/

If you have any clues to help me, 
thank you.

Comment: Why can you not use lists for this?

Comment: Your HTML structure is bad. Betters is use list of three separate <li> and in each use H1, H2 tags.

Comment: @ldtcoop it is a modification for an already existing project and I do not want to modify the structure used by several pages )=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hacky idea but if you know approximately how many consecutive sections you will have it may work.

This example will work for 4 consecutive sections. Note how the last one is wrong:

```css
#container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container div {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.element {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

[data-id=title-2] {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

[data-id=title-3] {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

[data-id=title-2]~.element,
[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id=title-2]~.element,
[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id=title-2]~.element,
[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id=title-2]~.element {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

[data-id=title-3]~.element,
[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id=title-3]~.element,
[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id=title-3]~.element,
[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id=title-3]~.element {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="element">Element A</div>
  <div class="element">Element A</div>
  <div class="element">Element A</div>

  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-3">Title 3</div>
  <div class="element">Element B</div>
  <div class="element">Element B</div>

  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="element">Element C</div>
  <div class="element">Element C</div>
  <div class="element">Element C</div>

  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-3">Title 3</div>
  <div class="element">Element D</div>
  <div class="element">Element D</div>
  <div class="element">Element D</div>

  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="element">wrong</div>
  <div class="element">wrong</div>
  <div class="element">wrong</div>
</div>
```

We can add more selectors and the last section will work:

```css
#container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container div {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.element {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

[data-id=title-2] {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

[data-id=title-3] {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

[data-id=title-2]~.element,
[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id=title-2]~.element,
[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id=title-2]~.element,
[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id=title-2]~.element,
[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id=title-2]~.element {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

[data-id=title-3]~.element,
[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id=title-3]~.element,
[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id=title-3]~.element,
[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id=title-3]~.element,
[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id*=title]~.element~[data-id=title-3]~.element {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="element">Element A</div>
  <div class="element">Element A</div>
  <div class="element">Element A</div>

  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-3">Title 3</div>
  <div class="element">Element B</div>
  <div class="element">Element B</div>

  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="element">Element C</div>
  <div class="element">Element C</div>
  <div class="element">Element C</div>

  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-3">Title 3</div>
  <div class="element">Element D</div>
  <div class="element">Element D</div>
  <div class="element">Element D</div>

  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="element">correct</div>
  <div class="element">correct</div>
  <div class="element">correct</div>
</div>
```

The trick behind this is that we increase the specifity based on the previous section to make sure we will always apply the correct styles

Comment: very interesting, there are less than 20 consecutive elements, I think this method should work, look forward to testing it on Monday,

thank you all and have a good weekend

Comment: thank you, this method allowed me to solve the problem even if my "css" code takes up a lot of space

Answer (score 0):

You should use this `+` selector instead, it select element that placed immediately after your preceded slelector:

```
#container [data-id=title-3] + .element {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

#container [data-id=title-2] + .element {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

If you have the another `.element` div under it, add these rules, combine `~` and `+` :

```
#container [data-id=title-3] + .element ~ .element {
   margin-left: 40px;
}

#container [data-id=title-2] + .element ~ .element {
   margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: It seems to me to be working, I'll try it on Monday, thank you.

Comment: Your welcome, please mark my answer as correct if it does work, thank you too!

Comment: I unfortunately test as there may be several "elements" that follow each other this one will not be aligned correctly

https://jsfiddle.net/2rwc9sbk/1/
My "Element D" should be aligned at the same level as "Title 2"

Comment: I tried but I have an alignment problem for some element (plus I don't know how many elements can follow each other) 

https://jsfiddle.net/3zuae71r/

I don't know if this is possible with css, I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

You could nest the `.element` divs inside the title divs. Just need to change `height` to `min-height` on the `#container div` elements.

```css
#container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container div {
  min-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.element {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

[data-id=title-2] {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

[data-id=title-3] {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">
    Title 2
    <div class="element">Element A</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-3">
    Title 3
    <div class="element">Element B</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="title" data-id="title-1">Title 1</div>
  <div class="title" data-id="title-2">
    Title 2
    <div class="element">Element C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't have to change the structure but thank you for the suggestion )=